# Echo Related Table Row If Not Empty - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, conditional-statements

I want to echo rows from `comments` table where comments exist made on `entries` table. But not show them if comments are empty. My code below currently would show comments made on blog entries but doesn't show them if empty. **In other words: both blog entries and comments show up but when you echo entries but do not have comments would not even echo anything** The echo statement on the else doesn't even work. I'm pretty sure I'm doing this all wrong. I have a code where I did.

```
//if a blog post was made
//echo all the blog post
//If you select a particular blog post
//Echo that particular blog post

if (!empty($postID)) {
  $command = "select t1.blogID t1blogID, t1.author t1author, t1.date t1date, 
             t1.entry, t2.commentID, t2.author t2author, t2.date t2date, 
             t2.comments from $table_name t1, $table_name2 t2 
             where t1.blogID = t2.blogID and t1.blogID = $postID";
  $result = $db->query($command);
while ($data = $result->fetch_object()) {
  // I figured I'd create a variable here
  $postID = $data->t1blogID; 
  $t1author = $data->t1author;
  $t1date = $data->t1date;
  $entry = $data->entry;
  $commentID = $data->commentID;
  $t2author = $data->t2author;
  $t2date = $data->t2date;
  $comments = $data->comments;

  //So I can create this conditional statement 
  // if there is no comment
  if (!empty($commentID)) {
   echo "<TR><TD>Blog ID ".$postID."</TD>";
   echo "<TD>".$t1author."</TD>";
    echo "<TD>".$t1date."</TD>";
    echo "<TD>".$entry."</TD></TR>\n";   
    echo "<TR><TD>Comment ID ".$commentID."</TD>";
    echo "<TD>".$t2author."</TD>";
    echo "<TD>".$t2date."</TD>";
    echo "<TD>".$comments."</TD></TR>\n";
  }
  else {
    echo "<TR><TD>Blog ID ".$postID."</TD>";
    echo "<TD>".$t1author."</TD>";
    echo "<TD>".$t1date."</TD>";
    echo "<TD>".$entry."</TD></TR>\n";     
  }
  }
result->free();
```

Comment: You need to start with the sql query. When you run that from the command line or phpMyAdmin, does it even show the posts without comments?

Comment: It seems like you're contradicting yourself: *"I want to echo rows from comments table where comments exist made on entries table. `But not show them if comments are empty`. My code below currently `would show comments` made on blog entries `but doesn't show them if empty`."* (confused)

Comment: @jeroen you mean if you type select * from the table? Yes, I can select the records with no problem. The $command query statement works even if you were to type that on the database prompt.

Comment: @Fred-ii- ugh yes as per the suggestion below. I'll try to switch it so that if comments are empty etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try left join two table:

```
select t1.blogID t1blogID, t1.author t1author, t1.date t1date, t1.entry, t2.commentID, t2.author t2author, t2.date t2date, t2.comments from $table_name t1 LEFT JOIN $table_name2 t2 ON t1.blogID = t2.blogID where t1.blogID = $postID
```

would work.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `for empty comments you should check if(empty($comments)){ ........ }` ?

Comment: I think that might be it ugh I'll try that @Riad as per Fred -ii- code which what you pointed out.

Comment: actually for the else statement to work. if(!empty($comments)) {....} should be the checking in the existing code.

Comment: `if(!empty` = `not` empty --- while `if(empty` = is just that, if `empty`, so the syntax should follow the logic. *"for empty comments..."*

Comment: Behaves the same way no changes. It echo the blog entries and the comments entries should they exist. But then it "doesn't" echo anything at all when an entry doesn't have comments.

Comment: @mythoslife: would you please see the result of 
echo '<pre>';print_r($data);echo '</pre>'; 
and then get the decision of printing(echo) results.

Comment: @Riad I added inside the `if` and the `else`... Spits out something when there are comments, but empty otherwise.

Comment: When there are no comments in the "Post" then $data is empty?
would you try with left join like:

SELECT * FROM 
    (
    select t1.blogID t1blogID, t1.author t1author, t1.date t1date, 
    t1.entry from $table_name t1 where t1.blogID = $postID
    ) TABLE1 LEFT JOIN
    (
    select t2.blogID, t2.commentID, t2.author t2author, t2.date t2date, 
    t2.comments from $table_name t2 
    ) TABLE2 ON TABLE1.blogID = TABLE2.blogID

Comment: @Riad `"select t1.blogID t1blogID, t1.author t1author, t1.date t1date, t1.entry, t2.commentID, t2.author t2author, t2.date t2date, t2.comments from $table_name t1 LEFT JOIN $table_name2 t2 ON t1.blogID = t2.blogID where t1.blogID = $postID";` That works!

Comment: @Riad can you please add it as an answer so I can give you credit. Thanks again.

Comment: @Riad the query statement I've shown 53 min ago is the tweak that works better as far as left join on mysql that I know works at least.

Comment: yeah, works better as select * is not needed at all. edited one more time. :)

Answer (score 0):

I cant comment so i'll do it here.
I'm not sure if your SQL is right shouldnt it be a JOIN?

But obviously the $commentID is not empty so try:

```
if($commentID > 0)
```

Comment: $commentID should be the primary key i think for comments table.(?)
how can it be <= 0 ?

Comment: @YRM it should work but still doesn't. I must be looping incorrectly somehow.

Comment: @YRM SQL statement is proper you can do JOIN as well. This is MySQL specific query statement.

Comment: can you do a var_dump of $data and post one where there should be no comments?

Comment: @YRM that's the same `print_r($data);`? Empty on the ones with no comments (no echo) but spits out rows of every entries with comments.